# What is the rails way of rendering groups of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model can be described as following:

`One Forum has many Threads. One Thread has many Comments.`

Data is not denormalized; i.e. Threads has FK only leading to Forum and Comments has FK leading only to Thread.

What will be "The Rails Way" of selecting specific Threads and then rendering Comments in a template grouped by the thread they belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) here.

Define `has_many` and `belongs_to`relationships for your Forum<> Thread and Thread<>Comment

Querying using rails interface would be quite easy for you then. Refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Selecting commnets of specific threads(grouped by it)

```
Comment.where('thread_id in ?',[specific_thread_ids_to_search]).order('thread_ids')
```